# Log all network transaction via rsyslog

Tags: networking

I want to log all network transactions in Ubuntu.

network transaction such as the following:

- request to connect to specific port
- connected client to my Ubuntu
- connected time in connection
- client that ping my Ubuntu

And all network activity from Ubuntu.

I tried `tail /var/logauth.log` but the info isn't very useful.

In my rsyslog config, I have:

```
news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice
```

But the folder `news` does not exist.

Comment: Are you behind a NAT?

Comment: i directly connect to internet via ADSL @aroll605 and eth0 interface

Comment: @Toroidal:please review my edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The news filters you specified will log traffic from an NNTP server.  It sounds like you want network traffic.  You'll need a program that logs that sort of information.  Check out netstat or nagios.

`/var/logauth.log` is only going to give you information on attempts to log into your box, not things such as pinging or connecting to a specific port.